# Logging antlr v3 parser activity

Tags: java, antlr

I would like to be able to log the parsing process of an Antlr v3 (3.0.1 to be precise) generated grammar. I tried to use a DebugTreeParser but it does nothing, looks like its methods never get called.

Ideally, I would like to be able to output something like the following, a trace of tried/executed rules:

```
 parsing: program (token: Foo)
 parsing: statements (token: Foo)
 parsing: statement (token: Foo)
 parsing: block (token: Foo)
 parsed: block -> false (at 0)
 parsing: method call (token: Foo)
 parsing: variable (token: Foo)
 parsed: variable -> true (at 1)
 ...
```

Here is my parsing code:

```
        CharStream cs = new ANTLRReaderStream(script);
        MyLexer lex = new MyLexer(cs);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        MyParser parser = new MyParser(tokens);
        return new Program(makeProgram((Tree) parser.program().getTree()));
```

I tried a solution found on the Antlr Wiki:

```
 ...
 ParseTreeBuilder builder = new ParseTreeBuilder("prog");

 MyParser parser = new MyParser(tokens);
 parser.setTreeAdaptor(new DebugTreeAdaptor(builder, parser.getTreeAdaptor()));
```

But the builder outputs nothing interesting.

Maybe there is an option to activate in the source grammar to generate a debug-compatible parser?

Comment: What part of the parsing process are you interested in logging? Could you give an example of what ideal log output would look like?

Comment: updated description to provide an idea of what I expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, generate your grammar using the `-debug` command-line option. Once this is done, your token parser will have additional, debug-centric constructors available that allow you to use a custom `DebugEventListener` or a built-in one. Since you're going for custom logging, here is an example solution using custom `DebugEventListener`s to get you started.

Here's the grammar I'll use for testing. It may contain problems.

#### DebugMe.g

```
grammar DebugMe;


compilationUnit : statements EOF;
statements      : statement+;
statement       : block | call | decl;
block           : LCUR statements RCUR;    
call            : ID LPAR arglist? RPAR SEMI;
arglist         : ID (COMMA ID)*;    
decl            : VAR ID EQ expr SEMI;
expr            : add_expr;     
    
add_expr        : primary_expr ((PLUS|MINUS) primary_expr)*;    
primary_expr    : STRING | ID | INT | LPAR expr RPAR;    
    
VAR: 'var';   
ID: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
INT: ('0'..'9')+;
STRING: '"' ~('\r'|'\n'|'"')* '"';
SEMI: ';';
LPAR: '(';
RPAR: ')';
LCUR: '{';
RCUR: '}';
PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';    
COMMA: ',';
EQ: '=';
WS: (' '|'\t'|'\f'|'\r'|'\n') {skip();};
```

Here is the test program I'll use. Note that I omitted the implementation of `newEventListener`.

#### TestDebugMeGrammar.java

```
public class TestDebugMeGrammar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CharStream input = new ANTLRStringStream("var x = 3; print(x);");

        DebugMeLexer lexer = new DebugMeLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        DebugMeParser parser = new DebugMeParser(tokens, newEventListener());

        parser.compilationUnit();
    }
    //...
}
```

I'm not overly familiar with how `DebugEventListener` gets called by the parser, so I'll start out with a simple `Proxy` implementation that dumps out every call with a minimal amount of hassle:

```
//TestDebugMeGrammar.java

    private static DebugEventListener newEventListener() {
        return (DebugEventListener) Proxy.newProxyInstance(TestDebugMeGrammar.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { DebugEventListener.class },
                new DebugListenerHandler());
    }

    public static class DebugListenerHandler implements InvocationHandler {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
                throws Throwable {

            // simply print out the method call.
            System.out.print(method.getName());

            if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
                System.out.print(": ");
                for (int i = 0, count = args.length; i < count; ++i) {
                    Object arg = args[i];
                    if (arg == null) {
                        System.out.printf("<(null)> ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.printf("<%s> ", arg.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The output is extensive, but it gives a good idea of what the listener hears.

```
enterRule: <DebugMe.g> <compilationUnit> 
commence
location: <4> <1> 
enterAlt: <1> 
location: <5> <7> 
enterRule: <DebugMe.g> <statements> 
location: <7> <1> 
enterAlt: <1> 
location: <8> <7> 
enterSubRule: <1> 
enterDecision: <1> <false> 
LT: <1> <[@0,0:2='var',<11>,1:0]> 
exitDecision: <1> 
enterAlt: <1> 
location: <8> <7> 
enterRule: <DebugMe.g> <statement> 
location: <10> <1> 
enterDecision: <2> <false> 
LT: <1> <[@0,0:2='var',<11>,1:0]> 
exitDecision: <2> 
enterAlt: <3> 
location: <13> <7> 
enterRule: <DebugMe.g> <decl> 
...
```

Here's a small, focused listener based on what I've gleaned from the above. The output is closer to what you want, and may serve as a useful starting point for you.

```
//TestDebugMeGrammar.g
    //redefinition
    private static DebugEventListener newEventListener() {
        return new SimpleDebugEventListener();
    }

    private static class SimpleDebugEventListener extends
            BlankDebugEventListener {
        
        private Token lastToken;
        @Override
        public void LT(int i, Object t) {
            System.out.println("Read object \"" + t + "\"");
        }

        @Override
        public void LT(int i, Token t) {
            if (!t.equals(lastToken)){
                System.out.println("Read input \"" + t.getText() + "\"");
                lastToken = t;
            }
        }

        @Override
        //public void enterRule(String ruleName) { // <-- ANTLR 3.0.1
        public void enterRule(String grammarFileName, String ruleName) { //<-- ANTLR 3.4
            System.out.println("Entered rule " + ruleName);
        }

        @Override
        //public void exitRule(String ruleName) { // <-- ANTLR 3.0.1
        public void exitRule(String grammarFileName, String ruleName) { //<-- ANTLR 3.4
            System.out.println("Exited rule " + ruleName);
        }

        @Override
        public void consumeToken(Token token) {
            System.out.println("Consumed \"" + token.getText() + "\"");
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Entered rule compilationUnit
Entered rule statements
Read input "var"
Entered rule statement
Entered rule decl
Consumed "var"
Read input "x"
Consumed "x"
Read input "="
Consumed "="
Entered rule expr
Entered rule add_expr
Entered rule primary_expr
Read input "3"
Consumed "3"
Exited rule primary_expr
Read input ";"
Exited rule add_expr
Exited rule expr
Consumed ";"
Exited rule decl
Exited rule statement
Read input "print"
Entered rule statement
Entered rule call
Consumed "print"
Read input "("
Consumed "("
Read input "x"
Entered rule arglist
Consumed "x"
Read input ")"
Exited rule arglist
Consumed ")"
Read input ";"
Consumed ";"
Exited rule call
Exited rule statement
Read input "<EOF>"
Exited rule statements
Consumed "<EOF>"
Exited rule compilationUnit
```

---

I originally tested and ran the above code using ANTLR 3.4. I retested it with ANTLR 3.0.1, per your specs, and the only change you'll need to make this work is in the `SimpleDebugEventListener` class. I have updated the code to indicate where the change is needed and what that change is.

---

Just for fun, here is a modified `SimpleDebugEventListener` that prints output that I think is more similar to your logging goals.

```
    private static class SimpleDebugEventListener extends
            BlankDebugEventListener {

        private LinkedList<String> activeRules = new LinkedList<String>();

        @Override
        public void enterRule(String grammar, String ruleName) {  //ANTLR 3.4
            activeRules.add(ruleName);
        }

        @Override
        public void exitRule(String grammar, String ruleName) { //ANTLR 3.4
            activeRules.removeLast();
        }

        @Override
        public void consumeToken(Token token) {
            System.out.printf("%s consumed \"%s\"%n", formatRules(),
                    token.getText());
        }

        private String formatRules() {
            if (activeRules.size() == 1) {
                return activeRules.getLast();
            } else { 
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                boolean first = true;
                for (String rule : activeRules){
                    if (!first){
                        builder.append(" -> ");
                    } else { 
                        first = false;
                    }
                    builder.append(rule);
                }
                
                return builder.toString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
compilationUnit -> statements -> statement -> decl consumed "var"
compilationUnit -> statements -> statement -> decl consumed "x"
compilationUnit -> statements -> statement -> decl consumed "="
compilationUnit -> statements -> statement -> decl -> expr -> add_expr -> primary_expr consumed "3"
compilationUnit -> statements -> statement -> decl consumed ";"
compilationUnit -> statements -> statement -> call consumed "print"
compilationUnit -> statements -> statement -> call consumed "("
compilationUnit -> statements -> statement -> call -> arglist consumed "x"
compilationUnit -> statements -> statement -> call consumed ")"
compilationUnit -> statements -> statement -> call consumed ";"
compilationUnit consumed "<EOF>"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a thorough and detailed answer! I should have tried the `-debug` flag for a start...